# client/server sending segments

Tags: networking, server, client

I had a question on my exam that said From the client's point of view, the ___ directs segments to a particular process on a server. I put source port number and it was wrong. I am thinking now that is the destination port number, because it will help know where the segments are going. Is this correct? 
The other options are source IP address, and destination IP adress

Answer (score 0):

The destination IP address is used to address the host. The destination port number for e.g. TCP or UDP is used as a subaddress on the host to address the service or process on the host.